# How to find connectivity in a matrix and store the data in a stack data structure in C

Tags: c, algorithm, stack

I need to verify connectivity in a matrix in spots, for example given a x coordinate and a y coordinate, I need to know which and how many blocks are connected to the one pointed by (x,y).
Currently I'm holding the blocks to check in a stack data structure but I'm stuck in a loop: the one to check leaves the stack and the ones acquired by that goes into the stack, after that leaves another one from the stack (one originated by the 1st one) and so on until the stack is empty. The problem are the pointers and the linked list, since the stack is dynamic.

```
struct1 *Pop(struct1 *StackHead){
    struct1 *aux = StackHead, *prev = NULL;
    struct2 *coord_aux;
    if(StackHead->next == NULL){
        coord_aux = StackHead->coordi;
        StackHead = NULL;       
    }else {
        while (aux->next != NULL){
            prev = aux;
            aux = aux->next;
        }
        coord_aux = aux->coordenada;
        prev->next = NULL;
    }

    return coord_aux;
}
```

The problem here is that I am running a while loop inside another function to pop an element and process it while (StackHead != NULL) but since I need the coord_aux info I can't free the block associated, which means the StackHead is never empty.

The struct2 is a parameter of the struct1 which holds 2 integers -> the coordinates (x,y) of that block

Thanks in advance

Comment: `StackHead = NULL;` serves no purpose as `StackHead` is not used later in the function.  `StackHead = NULL;` does not affect the pointer used by the calling code either.  Please post a [mcve].

Comment: StackHead will be used in next iterations of the function, since popping one element from the Stack List can and will produce more elements that afterwards are pushed and popped one at a time and so on...
Working on minimal reproducible example

Comment: `StackHead = NULL` in `Pop()` does not affect any pointer in the calling code.  The `StackHead` does not affect a later iteration.